# Mysql join user table with other table

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have two tables:

> document table (documentID, userID) and sers table (UserID, FirstName, LastName).

For example

document table:

```
documentID = 1 | userID = 2 | modifiedUser = 2
documentID = 3 | userID = 1 | modifiedUser = 1
```

user table:

```
userID = 1 | firstName = Bob  | lastName = Hope
userID = 2 | firstName = John | lastName = Doe
```

I need SQL query to select all columns from document table but should concatenate first and last name of user rather than userID

My output should be :

```
documentID = 1 | userID = John Doe | modifiedUser = John Doe
documentID = 3 | userID = Bob Hope | modifiedUser = Bob Hope
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***you need this:***

```
SELECT A.documentID, 
CONCAT_WS(' ', B.firstName, B.lastName) AS userID 
FROM document  A, USER B 
WHERE B.userID = A.userID 
ORDER BY A.documentID;
```

***output should like:***

```
+----------+----------+
|documentID| userID   |
+----------+----------+
|   1      | jhon doe |
+----------+----------+
|   3      | bob hope |
+----------+----------+
```

***update:1***

```
SELECT A.documentID, 
CONCAT_WS(' ', B.firstName, B.lastName) AS userID, 
CONCAT_WS(' ', B.firstName, B.lastName) AS modifiedUser  
FROM document  A, USER B 
WHERE B.userID = A.userID 
ORDER BY A.documentID;
```

***output like:***

```
+----------+----------+------------+
|documentID| userID   |modifiedUser|
+----------+----------+------------+
|   1      | jhon doe |  jhon doe  |
+----------+----------+------------+
|   3      | bob hope |  bob hope  |
+----------+----------+------------+
```

***http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws***

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**Updated the query to reflect the changes in the question:

Simple `JOIN` should do:

```
SELECT documentID, 
 concat(u.firstName,' ',u.lastName) AS userID,
 concat(mu.firstName,' ',mu.lastName) AS userID 
FROM document
JOIN user u ON (u.userID=document.userID)
JOIN user mu ON (mu.userID=document.modifiedUser);
```

Comment: suppose another user column present in document. then how to proceed. i have updated my question ..

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the JOIN clause when I edited the answer. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.document_id, u.firstName||u.lastName AS 'user_id'
FROM document d JOIN user u
ON d.userID=u.userID;
```

This should work.

Comment: suppose another user column present in document. then how to proceed. i have updated my question

Comment: SELECT d.document_id, u.firstName||u.lastName AS 'user_id', 
u1.firstName||u1.lastName AS 'modified_user_id'
FROM document d JOIN user u
ON d.userID=u.userID
JOIN user u1 
ON d.userID=u1.modifiedUser;

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT d.documentID, concat_ws(' ', u.firstName, u.lastName) AS userID 
    FROM document d, user u 
   WHERE u.userID = d.userID ;
```